# How to inject Translator in webTestCase?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I use Symfony 5.3 and in my functionnal Tests, I try to use the translator. This is how I did :

```php
/**
     * @test
     * @dataProvider provideFields
*/
 public function it_is_fail_with_incorrect_fields(
        string $email,
        string $alias,
        string $password,
        string $repeat_password,
        string $selector,
        string $error,
        string $field
    )
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $translator = static::getContainer()->get('translator');

        dump($translator->trans('user.email.format'));
```

When I dump I've got the result 'user.email.format' instead of my message. I don't know why I don't have the result, any idea ?

Comment: Are you using a special translation domain or is the translation stored in the default `messages` domain? Did you set up a fallback language? Have you tried calling `setLocale()` on the translator or passing in the locale you want to translate to in the method call like this: `$translator->trans('user.email.format', [], null, 'fr_FR')`. If that is it, I assume that the problem is with the `LocaleListener` not being called, because you don't really use the client only the booted kernel.

Comment: hi @dbrumann ,
I'm using the translation stored in my messages.fr.xlf. The langage is set up and I've already use the translator in my form and route's controller and it works. I've tried your way `$translator->trans('user.email.format', [], null, 'fr_FR')` but still doesn't work